# Highlight the list item in an ASP.NET ListView Control

Tags: asp.net, listview

I am using an ASP.NET LisView Control

```
<ul id="Category" class="row list-inline">
    <asp:ListView ID="categoryList"
        ItemType="products.Models.Category"
        runat="server"
        SelectMethod="GetCategories"
        >
        <SelectedItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("ProductsByCategoryRoute", new {categoryName = Item.CategoryName}) %>" class="selectedanchor">
                    <%#: Item.CategoryName %>
                </a>
            </li>
        </SelectedItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("ProductsByCategoryRoute", new {categoryName = Item.CategoryName}) %>">
                    <%#: Item.CategoryName %>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate></ItemSeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</ul>
```

I want to highlight the hyperlink that gets clicked. I have written some css for the same and am using the selecteditemtemplate to apply the css class to the hyperlink but this is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put what you have tried so far.

Comment: My friend that's exactly what I have done. Check the SelectedItemTemplate.

Comment: You can use `a:visited` for the same. `selectedanchor:visited`

Comment: On postback it won't work, have already tried that.

Comment: In that case you have to keep the data and the visited `true` `false` in you data and bind accordingly. Change the css class accordingly. Note that `SelectedItemTemplate` is not same as visited.

Comment: can you please explain 'accordingly'. Some code would be appreciated